# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404. Whitable Error page in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

> I am using spring boot for my application when I run it it show me an
>   error   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you
>   are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Jun 06 11:44:29 IST 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available I use my sql for database 
>   and sql youg for database editor but it is not able to connect with
>   database
>
> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.material</groupId>
    <artifactId>MaterialComp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MaterialComp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> UserEntity.java

```
package com.material.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="userentity")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

> UserRepo.java

```
package com.material.Repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.material.Entity.UserEntity;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>{

}
```

> controller.java

```
package com.material.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.material.Entity.UserEntity;
import com.material.Repo.UserRepository;
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(path="user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<UserEntity> getUsers(){
        return userRepo.findAll();

    }
}
```

> application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/ecommerce
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
```

Comment: That error shows up because you're accessing a resource that does not exist. The URL you're supposed to request to is `GET http://localhost:8080/user/get`

Comment: @lipudalai Why is it that the `UserRepository`  class doesn't have the `@Respository` annotation in the code that you shared. You need the annotation for spring to create the default crud implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few tricky things here.

Firstly, you've configured your server to listen on localhost:4200, which is fine.
You've done that with this line:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200")
```

Next you've told spring this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="user")
```

Spring will take `user` and add it to `http://localhost:4200`. So it's listening now on `http://localhost:4200user` - this isn't what you want, try adding a `/` so that your request mapping looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/user")
```

Your application should now be listening on http://localhost:4200/user. Great!

Next, to hit the getUsers method, you've defined `@GetMapping("/get")` which, combined with your other annotations will mean that to hit getUsers you need to make a GET to `http://localhost:4200/user/get`, assuming everything was working correctly.

A little trick is that `@GetMapping` is actually an alias for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` - so to tidy this up you could delete `@RequestMapping(path="user")` and just use

@GetMapping(value = "/users") and this would mean that a `GET` against `http://localhost:4200/user` would activate your `getUsers` method.